# Django Twitter API error: "code":215,"message":"Bad Authentication data."

Tags: python, django, twitter

I am making a bot detection system for Twitter. I am facing problem in getting user account info. I have successfully made twitter authentication but when requesting user account info, I am getting this error

> "code":215,"message":"Bad Authentication data."

My views.py code

```
from django.http import HttpResponse,HttpResponseRedirect
from django.urls import reverse
from django.shortcuts import render,redirect
from werkzeug.utils import redirect

from .forms import UserLoginForms
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login, logout
import requests

def home(request):


    screenname = 'BarackObama'
    r = requests.get('https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=' + screenname + '&count=2')
    print(r.text)

    return render(request,'home.html')

def main_login_page(request):
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/accounts/twitter/login')

def user_logout(request):
    logout(request)
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse(home))
```

My settings.py file. Here I am adding it because in it, at the end I have added my twiiter app key and secret.

```
"""
Django settings for FYPDjango project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 2.1.7.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/
"""

import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = '+w5xq2*@!0zxi)q2+psrk+p^jd$-ndh9(z(dohb6xx9)aa)0z7'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['mysite.com' , 'localhost', '127.0.0.1']


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'social_django',
# The following apps are required:
    'django.contrib.sites',

    'allauth',
    'allauth.account',
    'allauth.socialaccount',
    'allauth.socialaccount.providers.twitter',
]

SITE_ID = 1

# for oauth
AUTHENTICATION_BACKEND = [
    # 'social_core_backends.twitter.TwitterOAuth',
    # 'social_core.backends.google.GoogleOAuth2'
    'allauth.account.auth_backends.AuthenticationBackend '
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'social_django.middleware.SocialAuthExceptionMiddleware'
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'FYPDjango.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')]
        ,
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                'social_django.context_processors.backends',
                'social_django.context_processors.login_redirect',  #For redirecting via login page
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'FYPDjango.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

#edited me here
STATIC_DIRS = 'static'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    STATIC_DIRS,
]

SOCIAL_AUTH_TWITTER_KEY = 'xqTh9nHX5x4vN6AxKtnSjYsgs  '
SOCIAL_AUTH_TWITTER_SECRET = '4qu506zZFM0t5rcxSb7mWvjMxx3UzxCY7hdlD2Am7ScnwMDhm6'
#
# SOCIAL_AUTH_GOOGLE_OAUTH2_KEY = '670284466947-42q8a99b1i76achlua9r4oq9as4kubu6.apps.googleusercontent.com'
# SOCIAL_AUTH_GOOGLE_OAUTH2_SECRET = 'SYx2HCGS1dbCfOIAkrN_ru9E'

LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'home'
```

My urls.py file

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path,include

from FYPapp.views import user_logout, home, main_login_page

urlpatterns = [
    # I want to add my app in the project so do this

    path('',home,name='home'),
    path('login',main_login_page,name='main_login_page'),
    path('logout',user_logout,name='user_logout'),
    path('accounts/', include('allauth.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),

]
```

I am new to Django. So please help me with that problem. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is not a problem with Django but with your Twitter API access. Per the "[Getting Started](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/basics/getting-started)" doc, you need to first apply for an account and receive your consumer key and access token. Then you need to use those to [authenticate](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/basics/authentication/overview/oauth) before making your call to `statuses/user_timeline`

Consider using the python package [tweepy](http://www.tweepy.org) to make accessing the API easier.

Comment: knap, I have the twitter api account. And also I am authenticating using this twitter developer account. but after that I am getting this error

Comment: I have edited the question. Can you please check it again